# How to access group details in SAML

Tags: openam, opensso

I am creating ID provider through OpenAM, I get the user details in the SAML assertion returned, but I also want to get the user group details in the assertion,how can I get it. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches ...

1) create custom attribute mapper which allows to put group info into assertion

2) create post auth plugin which puts group info in session property and use default attribute mapper

3) leverage data store and data store config

This depends on your data store being used
If the data store (e.g. LDAP based Directory Server) provides an (operational) attribute which shows group info at the user entry then you can map this as attribute in data store config and use default attribute mapper.

E.g. OpenDJ provides 'isMemberOf' , but you will see real group DNs as values for the mapped attribute